# URL shows subdirectory named 'en' although it is not in the public_html

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, softaculous

I am using Softaculous to install WordPress from Cpanel on the root public_html directory, and when the installation finishes successfully, and after opening the domain it opens like this: [www.somewebsite.com/en](http://www.somewebsite.com/en), although there is no dirctory in public_html with the name 'en'. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: I think `en` refers here to the language of the website.

Comment: No I added it when installing for the first time using softaculous as subdirectory and removed it later but it still it shows.